# SequelizeEagerLoadingError with Sequelized

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, mysql2

I'm getting an error when trying to run a Sequelized query. The query works when I am only asking for a User, but breaks when I add 'include' and try to join with another table (the blogs table).

Here is my User model:

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/connection');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
// create our User model
class User extends Model {
    checkPassword(loginPw) {
        return bcrypt.compareSync(loginPw, this.password);
    }
}
// define table columns and configuration
User.init(
    {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        username: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                // this means it must be at least 4 characters
                len: [4]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        //(password hashing)
        hooks: {
            // set up beforeCreate lifecycle 'hook'
            async beforeCreate(newUserData) {
                newUserData.password = await bcrypt.hash(newUserData.password, 10);
                return newUserData;
            },
            // set up beforeUpdate lifecyle
            async beforeUpdate(updatedUserData) {
                updatedUserData.password = await bcrypt.hash(updatedUserData.password, 10);
                return updatedUserData;
            }
        },
        sequelize,
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true,
        underscored: true, 
        modelName: 'user'
    }
);

module.exports = User;
```

Here is my Blog Model:

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/connection');

class Blog extends Model{};

Blog.init(
    {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        blog_title: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        blog_text: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(6000),
            allowNull: false,
        },
        user_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            references: {
                model: 'user',
                key: 'id'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        sequelize,
        freezeTableName: true,
        underscored: true,
        modelName: 'blog'
    }
);

module.exports = Blog;
```

Here are my associations inside the Index file:

```
const User = require('./User');
const Blog = require('./Blog');

// User can have many Blogs
User.hasMany(Blog, {
    foreignKey: 'user_id'
});
Blog.belongsTo(User, {
    foreignKey: 'user_id'
});

module.exports = { User, Blog }
```

And here are is my route. It works perfectly fine without the include option.

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const User = require('../../models/User');
const Blog = require('../../models/Blog');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    User.findAll({
        attributes: { exclude: ['password']},
        include: [
            {
                model: Blog,
            }
        ]
    })
    .then(dbUserData =>
        res.json(dbUserData))
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json(err);
    })
})
module.exports = router;
```

This is the error I get when I try the route:

```
EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: blog is not associated to user!
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this problem.

I imported my models like this:

```
const User = require('../../models/User');
const Blog = require('../../models/Blog');
```

They should have been imported like this:

```
const { User, Blog } = require('../../models);
```

That way the models are pulled from the index file after the associations have been assigned to them.

Credit to Sandrine Poissonnet who spotted my error.