# Receiving SequelizeEagerLoadingError when trying to fetch associated tables

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have to be honest, I'm really, really lost on this issue. I have four PostgreSQL tables that I'm trying to query via Node/Express/Sequelize. I created the four tables using models that were auto-generated with Sequelize-CLI, and I migrated the tables using auto-generated migration templates from the same Sequelize-CLI. When I access the tables via PSQL, the proper foreign key connections do exist. Here are the relevant two of the four tables:

Program.js

```
'use strict';

const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize) => {
  class Program extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      this.hasMany(models.Track, {
        foreignKey: 'program_id'
      });
      this.belongsTo(models.Cart);
    }
  }
  Program.init({
    program_id: {
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false
    },
    program_length_ms: DataTypes.BIGINT,
    intra_track_fade_length_ms: DataTypes.BIGINT
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Program',
  });
  return Program;
};
```

Track.js

```
'use strict';

const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize) => {
  class Track extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      this.belongsTo(models.Program, {
        foreignKey: 'program_id'
      });
    }
  }
  Track.init({
    track_id: {
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false
    },
    spotify_track_id: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    program_id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false
    },
    program_position: DataTypes.BIGINT,
    track_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    duration_ms: DataTypes.BIGINT
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Track',
  });
  return Track;
};
```

Here are their relevant Sequelize-CLI migration scripts:

create-program.js

```
'use strict';
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Programs', {
      program_id: {
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        allowNull: false
      },
      program_length_ms: {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT
      },
      intra_track_fade_length_ms: {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Programs');
  }
};
```

create-track.js

```
'use strict';
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Tracks', {
      track_id: {
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.UUID
      },
      spotify_track_id: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      program_id: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            model: {
                tableName: 'Programs'
            },
            key: 'program_id'
        }
      },
      program_position: {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT
      },
      track_name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      duration_ms: {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Tracks');
  }
};
```

And here is the snippet of back-end Node/Express script (nested inside of a transaction) that I'm hoping to use to essentially produce the same result as `SELECT * FROM "Programs" JOIN "Tracks" ON "Tracks.program_id" = "Programs.program_id"`:

```
const resultLibrary = await Program.findAll({
    include: [
        Track
    ]
});
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Tried to execute the statement that is included in the above text. Expected to receive a nested JSON output from the Sequelize ORM, but instead received:

```
Executing (a63c5e44-d14e-4e55-b047-3f685c0be5bf): START TRANSACTION;
Executing (a63c5e44-d14e-4e55-b047-3f685c0be5bf): ROLLBACK;
Error while fetching user cart library:  EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: Track is not associated to Program!
    at Program._getIncludedAssociation (/Users/administrator/Documents/vscode_projects/8-track-using-spotify/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:565:13)
    at Program._validateIncludedElement (/Users/administrator/Documents/vscode_projects/8-track-using-spotify/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:502:53)
    at /Users/administrator/Documents/vscode_projects/8-track-using-spotify/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:421:37
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Program._validateIncludedElements (/Users/administrator/Documents/vscode_projects/8-track-using-spotify/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:417:39)
    at Program.findAll (/Users/administrator/Documents/vscode_projects/8-track-using-spotify/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1118:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async /Users/administrator/Documents/vscode_projects/8-track-using-spotify/server/controllers/library.js:44:26
    at async /Users/administrator/Documents/vscode_projects/8-track-using-spotify/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:507:18
    at async getLibrary (/Users/administrator/Documents/vscode_projects/8-track-using-spotify/server/controllers/library.js:25:18)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm genuinely shocked that the answer from Anthony Barragan ([SequelizeEagerLoadingError with Sequelized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71631110/sequelizeeagerloadingerror-with-sequelized)) applied to my case, as well: when using Sequelize-CLI-generated helper functions, all models have to be imported as specified in that answer in order to function properly.