# EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: users is not associated to properties

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm always getting SequelizeEagerLoadingError for every api that I call which includes another model.

index.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = {};
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const sequelize = require('../config/db');

fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function (file) {
    return (
      file.indexOf('.') !== 0 &&
      file !== basename &&
      file.slice(-3) === '.js' &&
      file !== 'associations.js' // Exclude the associations.js file from the loop
    );
  })
  .forEach(function (file) {
    var model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
    console.log('Loaded model:', model.name);
  });

const associations = require('./associations');
associations(sequelize);


Object.values(db).forEach((model) => {
  if (model.associate) {
    model.associate(db);
  }
});

db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize; 

module.exports = db;
```

associations.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize) => {
    const User = sequelize.models.users; 
    const Property = sequelize.models.properties;
    const Like = sequelize.models.likes;
    const Follow = sequelize.models.follows;
    const Wallet = sequelize.models.wallets;
    const Client = sequelize.models.clients;
    const Bid = sequelize.models.bids;

    console.log(Property);
    console.log(User);

    User.hasMany(Property, { foreignKey: 'createdBy', as: 'properties' });
    User.hasMany(Like, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
    User.hasOne(Wallet, { foreignKey: 'userId', as: 'wallet' });
    User.hasMany(Follow, { foreignKey: 'userId', as: 'follows' });

    Property.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'createdBy', as: 'user' });
    Property.hasMany(Like);
    Property.hasMany(Bid);

    Client.hasMany(Like, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
    Client.hasMany(Follow, { foreignKey: 'userId', as: 'follows' });
    Client.hasOne(Wallet, { foreignKey: 'userId', as: 'wallet' });

};
```

propertyModel.js (userModel.js is similar)

```
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');


module.exports = (sequelize) => {

  const Property = sequelize.define("properties", {
    id: { type: DataTypes.UUID, defaultValue: () => uuidv4(), primaryKey: true, allowNull: false },
    country: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    street: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    apartment: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    city: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    state: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    postal: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    name: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    type: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    structure: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    description: { type: DataTypes.TEXT },
    price: { type: DataTypes.DOUBLE },
    experience: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER },
    longitude: { type: DataTypes.DOUBLE },
    latitude: { type: DataTypes.DOUBLE },
    image: { type: DataTypes.JSON },
    createdBy: { type: DataTypes.UUID },
    createdAt: { type: DataTypes.DATE },
    updatedBy: { type: DataTypes.UUID },
    updatedAt: { type: DataTypes.DATE },
  });

   

  return Property;
};
```

property.Api

```
Property.findAll({
        attributes: [
            '*',
        ],
        include: [
            {
                model: User,
                as: 'user', 
            },
        ]
    })
```

A simple findAll works normally
Somehow the associations are not being implemented properly.
EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: users is not associated to properties!
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check if `Property` has non-empty `associations` prop right before `Property.findAll` call?

Comment: Also you didn't show code how you import models in property.api module

Comment: Hi Anatoly. Thanks for the tip. It was caused by the import models in propertyApi. I saw this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71631110/sequelizeeagerloadingerror-with-sequelized and checked it out. Managed to fix it